# In "Hi Score Girl", why does Akira Ono not speak at all?

Tags: hi-score-girl

Akira Ono is the main female character in the anime series *Hi Score Girl* (1 and 2) currently on Netflix. Her character never speaks, yet the reason for her silence, although used for certain effect/s, is not directly given.

I did some research, and one possible psychological reason, and which makes sense along with her character's story, is that she is being severely abused at home and this causes some children to completely and voluntarily stop talking. I was wondering if anyone else had any thoughts on this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the series and you may be on to something but it is also possible you are attempting to ascribe reality onto a fictional character where it was not intended. This could be like Shiina from Pet girl of Sakurasou who is implied to have Savant Syndrome / some form of neurodivergence although it is never said outright but it could also be like Sanji from One Piece having comically intense nosebleeds around beautiful women, one could theorize Sanji has a medical condition like hemophilia or PV but it's never explained and is clearly a gag which needs no scientific reason.

Answer (score 1):

According to the fandom wiki for *Hi Score Girl*, it says that she doesn't talk because it's a quirk of the anime. Heres a quote from the *Hi Score Girl* Wiki on Fandom

- "Despite being very smart, she never talked. Most likely it's part of the plot that she doesn't talk at all in the story. Most of the time, Haruo can read her facial expressions to guess what she's thinking and wanting. She makes small voices like "Umm", nodding, and shaking her head as a way to say yes or no."[Hi Score Girl Wiki](https://hiscoregirl.fandom.com/wiki/%C5%8Cno_Akira)

Other than that it might have to do with something else, but I am yet to read the manga. There are notions to the fact that she is able to speak but it's more of an off-screen thing. I got this particular idea from a Reddit post.

- "She can talk, she just never does it “on screen,” but there are references to her having conversations with other characters."

I couldn't get the link for this.

Comment: The quote from the wiki doesn't have a source and the way it's written sounds like a random kindly netizen theorizing why Akira doesn't talk as opposed to quoting something from the series or an interview with the creator, etc. I'd maybe reword that first part since it currently implies the wiki quote is an authoritative source which it could be if it were referencing something but doesn't seem to and/or find a more canon source (a quote from the manga/anime ideally or a statement of some sort by the creator)

Answer (score 0):

As per my view, Akira's character is mute because it gives some uniqueness in her character, so it can easily look attractive character to the user. The manga mentioned that she talk with her sister. It represents trust with her sister Haruo. Here Akira represents the trust like, her sister understands well without making fun of her. She is mute with other characters. Normally I think the character showed up kind and honest.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. We appreciate your contribution, but pure opinion/speculation answer is discouraged. Instead, please [edit] and try to back up the answer by providing supporting sources/references. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the suggestion, But I have answered with my opinion. I'm an anime user of "Hi Score Girl" so I posted.